# Batch rename of files that share the same prefix

Tags: bash, files, deduplication

I have a list of files on my server with a prefix that I want to de-dupe. These are completely different generated files.

It seems to be generated files with

```
{Title} - {yyyy-MM-dd}_{random} - {Description}.ts
```

For example:

```
Camera Recording - 2023-08-11_14 - Front Deck.ts
Camera Recording - 2023-08-11_14 - Back Deck.ts
Camera Recording - 2023-08-16_27 - Front Deck.ts
Camera Recording - 2023-08-16_36 - Front Deck.ts
Camera Recording - 2023-08-17_56 - Front Deck.ts
```

I need to be able to run a script that identifies duplicate prefixes of the following filesnames. Then changes the number prefix {random} part after the date

```
Camera Recording - 2023-08-11_14 - Front Deck.ts
Camera Recording - 2023-08-11_14 - Back Deck.ts
```

To become the following, the {random} needs to be replaced with a different value (other than 14)

```
Camera Recording - 2023-08-11_14 - Front Deck.ts
Camera Recording - 2023-08-11_68 - Back Deck.ts
```

Any advice on how to achieve this with a linux shell script?

Comment: Where does the `68` come from for your desired `Back Deck`?

Comment: Of your original set of five example files, which are duplicates of which?

Comment: @ChrisDavies I think is the `_{random}` part, `_14` is the dupe, the changed is `_14` *and* `_68`...

Comment: Welcome, please [edit] the question and state exactly what you mean by "prefix", what part is the duplicate you want to change, and how do you make the renaming (from `_14` to `_68`).

Comment: Would `fdupes --size --noempty .` be a useful starting point for listing groups of duplicates? (See `man fdupes` for the options to delete duplicates once found.) It checks file content not file name, though. Is that what's required? (Your question isn't clear on this point.)

Comment: @ChrisDavies OP states *"identifies duplicate **prefixes**"* which is an indicator that it's about duplicate parts of the *names* of the files and not the files themselves. Either way, yes, further clarification is needed.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, yes the _{random} part is the dupe, files are completely different so md5sum will be different.

Comment: Please clarify in your question. For example, would simply removing the random part be an acceptable method for dedupe?

Comment: removing the random part wont be acceptable as there could be multiple, ideally it would be great to generate another random value as part of the rename

Comment: @mysterio21_troy Could you tell us why you want to do this, what is the goal or the problem to be solved if any?

Comment: Sure, the software that I am using to play these recordings ends up merging the two files in the example into one recording to play. Looks like it extracts the date and treats the "random" number as a way to treat the same "date" as unique files.

So the goal of the script is to change the {random} part of the string to something unique that resolves this

Comment: `for f in *; do mv -v "$f" "${f/_/_$RANDOM_}"; done` ?

Comment: Please clarify the details IN THE QUESTION. Stop providing updates in the comments - they're easily missed. Make it easy for people to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using any POSIX awk if your file names cannot contain newlines:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r file; do
    if (( cnt++ % 2 )); then
        echo mv -- "$old" "$file"
    fi
    old="$file"
done < <(
    printf '%s\n' *.ts |
    awk '
        match($0,/ - [0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}_[0-9]+ - /) {
            beg = substr($0,1,RSTART+13)
            pfx = substr($0,RSTART+14,RLENGTH-17)
            end = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH-3)

            maxPfx[beg] = ( pfx > maxPfx[beg] ? pfx : maxPfx[beg] )
            key = beg RS pfx
            ends[key,++cnt[key]] = end
        }
        END {
            for ( key in cnt ) {
                split(key,begPfx,RS)
                beg = begPfx[1]
                for ( i=2; i<=cnt[key]; i++ ) {
                    pfx = begPfx[2]
                    end = ends[key,i]
                    printf "%s%s%s\n", beg, pfx, end
                    pfx = ++maxPfx[beg]
                    printf "%s%s%s\n", beg, pfx, end
                }
            }
        }
    '
)
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
mv -- Camera Recording - 2023-08-11_14 - Back Deck.ts Camera Recording - 2023-08-11_15 - Back Deck.ts
```

The above moves duplicates to a new prefix number that starts at 1 more than the existing highest prefix number for the string up to and including the date. You can't use a random number for the new prefix or you might get a new prefix that's the same as an existing prefix.

Remove the `echo` when done testing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution. It requires Bash 5 or later.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
declare -A SEEN
for FN in *.ts; do
    if [[ $FN =~ ('Camera Recording - ')([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}_)([0-9]+)( .*) ]]; then
        BEFORE=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        DATE=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        RNDM=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
        AFTER=${BASH_REMATCH[4]}

        KEY=$DATE$RNDM
        if [[ $BASH_VERSION < '5.2.0' ]]; then
            # Workaround for a bug in Bash fixed in 5.2.0
            KEY=${KEY@Q}
        fi
        while [[ -n ${SEEN[$KEY]} && $RNDM -lt 1000 ]]; do
            (( ++RNDM ))
            KEY=$DATE$RNDM
        done
        SEEN[$KEY]=1

        NEW_FILENAME=$BEFORE$DATE$RNDM$AFTER
        if [[ $FN != "$NEW_FILENAME" ]]; then
            mv -iv -- "$FN" "$NEW_FILENAME"
        fi
    fi
done
```

It doesn't re-randomize the {random} field, it just increments it.